# I want to call on mobile number but don't want user to show the dial number,to hide the privacy of dialled number

Tags: android, android-dialer

I am developing an app for a cab and have to implement the call facility.I am done with this calling feature but it is showing the dialed number in dialer, but I am in need to hide the dial number from the dialer.we are doing this just to make female passenger safe and comfortable while having the ride and after the ride.

Comment: User has to be able to see where does his device calling. There is no way, and should be no way to hide a number, as the user is paying money for the call. If you want not to show target number, use VoIP to deliver call to some backend, and from there - use some call gateway to call to the phone number.

Comment: As @VladMatvienko said it is not possible. The activity for calling has the complete controll until it is finished and your programm has the controll again. That is a design to prevent missusing the dialing function.

Comment: Create custom dialer for this purpose, where you can customize UI of dialer with some unrelated UX. http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/simpleDialer.html

Comment: @Santosh Yadav i think you can use Twillio for this its provides some functionalities like not showing user number ..its provides fake number..

Answer (score 0):

While calling Intent, Use Intent.ACTION_CALL. It will directly call at particular number without showing dialer to user.

Comment: it will show the phone app with the phone number it is calling.

Comment: I don't want anything, I'm not the question owner, but he wants the phone number not to be visible to the user.

Comment: I don't want to show the user which number is calling. i have already gone through Intent.ACTION_CALL but it will bring the phone app in front showing which no. is connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.ACTION_CALL it will directly call

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:100"));
                                startActivity(intent);
```